# How to get the FK from a parent text box to use in a child datagrid

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have two tables tblParent and tblChild with a FK in tblChild.
I put these two tables into a dataset and set the relationship to cascade
I can put both onto a form and add a parent and child records and then save and all works as it should.

But

I want to use text boxes for the parent not a datagrid.  When i DnD the fields and then add a child datagrid the child no longer automatically updates when i save, i get a missing FK exception

Please advise what i need ot do to get the same function as i have with two datagrids.

thanks

John

Comment: Anybody?  this is surely a very common situation.  Anyone coming from an Access background with subforms will be facing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one way of doing this, it may not be the right way but it does work

In the form load event I have disabled the relationship constraints:

```
    Me.Dataset.EnforceConstraints = False
```

then when i come to save:

```
    Me.TblParentBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TblChildBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Dataset)
    Me.TblChildTableAdapter.Update(Me.Dataset.tblChild)
```

after the tableadapter.updateall you can see the fk values propogate in the child datagrid and you can see the childIDs as negatives hence the final update on the child table

I hope this is helpful to someone.  If someone can give me a better approach I'd be grateful.

John